# Como transformar um “Projeto Unity5” em apk, para Android

Tags: android, unity-5, apk

Estou acompanhando aulas no YouTube de desenvolvimento de jogos com Unity5. 
Após a criação de um projeto no Unity5, gostaria de converte-lo para apk e testa em um celular, porem no meio da conversão ocorre um erro, fica pedindo o tempo todo para salvar em uma pasta. E mesmo depois de escolher a pasta, continua pedindo um local para salvar. 
Enfim, gostaria de saber se é preciso ter algum outro programa instalado para converte-lo. Se precisar, quais programas tenho que instalar??

Comment: Especifique o erro que está dando, adicione prints ou código para ajudar a solucionar o seu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No proprio unity voce consegue exporta para android criando um APK, porem precisa de instalar algumas coisas a mais, como o JDK da oraculo e SDK do android

Fiz um tutorial a respeito aqui http://www.studioscheckpoint.com/2015/09/como-configurar-e-criar-um-apk-no-unity.html

Comment: Entendi
Obrigadoo